# Why opencv3 requires libavcodec56 although opencv2 requires libavcodec57

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, libavcodec

I have installed opencv using apt-get. I got opencv2 with the following version and it works fine:

```
rover@rover_pi:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf $ python2.7
Python 2.7.13 (default, Nov 24 2017, 17:33:09) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'2.4.9.1'
```

Then I wanted to install opencv on a conda environment using pip. I got the following version

```
(olfatf)rover@rover_pi:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf $ pip list | grep opencv
opencv-python          3.4.0.14
```

However, I get the following error when I import the module:

```
(olfatf)rover@rover_pi:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf $ python
Python 3.4.3 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Aug 21 2015, 00:53:08) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/.conda/envs/olfatf/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libavformat.so.56: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I checked the install libavcodec library and I get the version 57.

```
(olfatf)rover@rover_pi:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf $ ls | grep libavformat
libavformat.a
libavformat.so
libavformat.so.57
libavformat.so.57.56.101
```

So I want to know why a later version of opencv requires an older version of libavcodec. Also, how can I installed both libavcodec56 and libavcodec57 on my machine ?

I use a raspberry pi with Raspbian Strech

Answer (score 1):

Its not that opencv requires it, Its that whoever compiled the binary of opencv you are using compiled it against libavcodec56. Easiest fix is to compile it yourself.

> Also, how can I installed both libavcodec56 and libavcodec57 on my machine ?

Don't. just compile and link against the same version.

Comment: Thank for replying. And how can I export the compiled opencv to my anaconda environment ? I did pip install because I wanted opencv to be installed on my anaconda environment. How can I export the compiled opencv to my anaconda environment ? Which file should I copy to which folder?

Comment: I don't know anything about anaconda.